# Kendo grid error missing when scrolling

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have simple kendo grid with scrolling. It shows 20 items at the beginning and when scrolling it gets dynamically more data and add to the grid.

Normally when getting data for first page when grid is loading, when dataService throws exception like this:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, this.T("System Error - retrying.").Text);
```

and my js method binded in configuration

```
Events(events => events.Error("acc.mp.gridErrorDialog"))
```

catch it and display proper message.

The problem is with next page, when grid is getting more data. 
I have seen that is happend when I toucht the scroll and scroll like 3 rows (even thought page size is 20), grid is trying to get data to the buffer to show them when I scroll 20 items.

But when error happens in this operation, the same like in first query, Kendo grid is not showing it immediately (becuse I didn't scrool yet 20 rows only it keeps its in his buffer) and nothing happen, and when I scroll to 20 rows spinner shows and all frezes. `Method acc.mp.gridErrorDialog` is not fired.

Grid initialization:

```
public static GridBuilder<T> InitializeGrid<T>(this GridBuilder<T> gridBuilder, string gridName, string dataBindAction, string controllerName, object routeValues) where T : class
        {
            if (gridBuilder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("gridBuilder");
            }

            return
                gridBuilder
                .Name(gridName)
                .TableHtmlAttributes(new { Class = "styled", cellpadding = "0", border = "0", margin = "0" })
                .HtmlAttributes(new { Class = "dynamicGridHeight" })
                .AutoBind(false)
                .DataSource(
                            dataSource =>
                            dataSource.Ajax()
                            .PageSize(ModelPortfolioConfigurationManager.GridPageSize)
                            .ServerOperation(true)
                            .Events(events => events.Error("acc.mp.gridErrorDialog"))
                            .Read(read => read.Action(dataBindAction, controllerName, AddAntispinnerParameter(routeValues))));
        }
```

and grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<ValidatedClientAccountViewModel>()
        .InitializeGrid(Naming.GridId(GridType.Upper), "GetClients, "ModelClients", new { modelTemplateId = Model.ModelId })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Model(model => model.Id(o => o.AccountId)))    
    .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template(
        @<text>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                 acc.mp.utils.bindLiveSearch($("#@Naming.GridId(GridType.Upper) input[name='txtSearch']"), function () { $("#@Naming.GridId(GridType.Upper) button[name='btnSearch']").click(); });                 
                 acc.mp.utils.searchGridFocus($("#@Naming.GridId(GridType.Upper) input[name='txtSearch']"));
             </script>
            </text>))
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.AccountId)
                    .ClientTemplate(ClientTemplates.UpperGridRowSelection)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
                    .HeaderTemplate(ClientTemplates.SelectAllCheckBox("cbLinkAll"))
                    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
                    .Filterable(true)
                    .Sortable(false)
                    .Width(35);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ClientReferenceNumber).Title(accountReference).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = accountReference });
            })
            .EnableScrollingAndPaging(ModelPortfolioConfigurationManager.GridPageSize)
            .Sortable()
            .Events(events =>
            {
                events.DataBinding("acc.mp.clientAccounts.upperGrid.dataBinding");
                events.DataBound("acc.mp.clientAccounts.upperGrid.dataBound");
                events.Change("acc.mp.clientAccounts.upperGrid.rowSelect");
            })
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug in kendo, You can track the status of the issue  here https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/749